# How to choose options for example the color globally for every fill between plot?

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

I want to set globally the color and other style options for every fill between plot in my document. How can I do this? I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\pgfplotsset{
compat=1.13,
axis lines=center,
every fill between plot/.append style={fill=blue,fill opacity=0.2}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
        \addplot[name path = f] gnuplot {x**2};%
        \addplot[name path = x] {0};

        \addplot fill between[of=f and x,soft clip={domain=2:4}];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I.e. the style options `fill=blue` and `fill opacity=0.2` are ignored.

Comment: Can you try setting `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fill between/.prefix style={....}}` somewhere in the preamble?

Comment: I just tried `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fill between/.prefix style={fill=green}}` but it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Oh OK. I'll check when I have access.

Answer (score 2):

This is most probably a bug, too, which I have also reported [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/112/).

It seems that at present (PGFPlots v1.13) the `every fill between plot` style only effects the legend. In contrast to that you can set your style for the `\addplot fill between`s in the `/tikz/fill between/every segment` style, but that doesn't seem to has an influence on the legend. On top of that it seems that the fill color is only applied when the fill between plot has a (empty) optional argument bracket, i.e. `\addplot [] fill between` ...

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \pgfplotsset{
    % only affects the legend
        every fill between plot/.append style={
            green,
            fill opacity=0.5,
        },
    % only effects the plot
        /tikz/fill between/every segment/.append style={
            red,    % <-- color is only applied when an empty `\addplot' argument is given
            fill opacity=0.2,
        },
        samples=100,
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot [name path = f] gnuplot [id=cos] {cos(x)};
            \addplot [name path = x] gnuplot [id=zero] {0};

            %
            \addplot fill between [
                of=f and x,
                soft clip={domain=-2:0}
            ];

            \addplot [
                % without giving these empty brackets,
                % no fill color is applied from the
                % `/tikz/fill between/every segment' style
            ] fill between [
                of=f and x,
                soft clip={domain=0:4}
            ];
            \legend{1,2,3,4}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]